# call user func array error after moved the site to new server

Tags: errors, callbacks

my wordpress site moved to a new server with cpanel. now after logged into wp-admin an error is showing.

```
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'showEntry' not found or invalid function name in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 406
```

can anybody please tell me why this is showing and how to solve this?

ok..i found out there this is related to a plugin. but i don't know the reason. please help me to find the reason why this is showing. the plugin part that contains this function is listed below: the plugin name is clinic

clinic.php

```
add_action('admin_print_scripts', 'showEntry');
```

appointment-book.php

```
<select name="eemail_subject_drop" id="eemail_subject_drop" onchange="showEntry(this.value)">
                <option value="">Select Email template</option>
  <?php echo $eemail_subject_drop_val; ?>
            </select>
```

settings.js

```
function showEntry(id)
{


 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var data = {
    action: 'template_action',
    id: id

};

// since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    //alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
     jQuery('textarea#mail_contents').text(response);
     });
     });
    }
```

view-subscriber.php

```
<select name="eemail_subject_drop" id="eemail_subject_drop" onchange="showEntry(this.value)">
                <option value="">Select Email template</option>
                <?php echo $eemail_subject_drop_val; ?>
            </select>
```

what is the error in these files. this warning happens when the site is moved to a new server with cpanel. please help me to solve this.

Comment: Did the database get copied over correctly? Are the correct theme/plugins enabled? What is "showEntry"?

Comment: yeah..everything is working perfectly. including cforms plugin. i don't know sir what is this showEntry. i checked that function in my theme function.php also but didn't find.

Comment: Shot in dark here, did you flush your permalinks after the migration. `showEntry` uses `$url`...

Comment: flush permalinks means? i just make in default and again make it as postname. is that u mean? sir, can u plz tell me what to do for that..

Comment: Could you do a search across all files in `wp-content` for "showEntry"?

Comment: Just go to your permalink page, and click update, thats all

Comment: @engelen: i searched .it shows "no records found".

Comment: @PieterGoosen: i did that.. it shows permalink updated. but the error message still present. :(

Comment: @barbieegal Could you search in your entire root directory then?

Comment: @engelen;; oh..i found one function called showEntry in a plugin file.but i don't know what this error means.. this error occurs only after the server shift.. :(

Comment: In what plugin file is it? Is that plugin activated?

Comment: yeah activated.. its a customized plugin.. and it cannot be removed because that plugin did most of the work in my site. nothing wrong with it work.evrythg is inserted and displaying correctly. this error is still present even after i make wp_debug false.

Comment: what is this call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback? do u know why this error is showing?

Comment: The error is saying that the showEntry function does not exist. If you are sure that the plugin is activated then maybe the plugin files did not copy over correctly.

Comment: okay..after reading ur comment i deactivated and deleted the plugin and again copied the fresh copy. then again when activated the same error showing.. :(

Comment: `showEntry` should be a php function, the two examples you've shown are javascript functions. if everything still works despite this function not existing, just comment out the `add_action('admin_print_scripts', 'showEntry');` line.

Comment: @Milo : i've commented that line and no problem with the plugin working. thanks frnd.. but one doubt other sites in which i used the same plugin is also shifted to new server ,but they are not displaying this error.. :(

Comment: the error is probably generated on all sites, you just have display of [php warnings](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) disabled on the ones where you don't see it.

Comment: @Milo: okays... why the admin_print_scripts shows this error when server changed? i'm sorry i am a newbie thats y asking these doubts..

Comment: because the server is configured differently - new server has display php warnings enabled, old server doesn't. error reporting isn't a function of WordPress, it's php that is displaying them.